# When I create @ManyToOne object should I add this object in the list on the another side of a relationship?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Does this matter for Hibernate or will it link both sides by default?

Here is an example of adding the entity to the list in the other side of the relation ( create Dish object and add it to the List of objects in Restaurant in constructor ).

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Dish extends AbstractNamedEntity {
    private double price;
    private LocalDate dateAdded;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    public void setRestaurant (Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    public Dish(String name, double price, Restaurant restaurant) {
        super(name);
        this.price = price;
        this.dateAdded = LocalDate.now();
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }
}
```

Other side of relation:

```
    @Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = {"votes", "dishes"})
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity {

    String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Dish> dishes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Vote> votes;

    public void addDish(Dish dish) {
        this.dishes.add(dish);
        dish.setRestaurant(this);
    }

    public void removeDish(Dish dish) {
        this.dishes.remove(dish);
        dish.setRestaurant(null);
    }

    public void addVote(Vote vote) {
        this.votes.add(vote);
        vote.setRestaurant(this);
    }

    public void removeVote(Vote vote) {
        this.votes.remove(vote);
        vote.setRestaurant(null);
    }

    public Restaurant(String name, String address) {
        super(name);
        this.address = address;
    }



    public List<Dish> getDishes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(dishes);
    }

    public List<Vote> getVotes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(votes);
    }
}
```

Should my Dish constructor look like this:

```
  public Dish(String name, double price, Restaurant restaurant) {
        super(name);
        this.price = price;
        this.dateAdded = LocalDate.now();
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
        restaurant.add(this);
    }
```

Or restaurant.add(this) can be omitted?

Comment: It should. Always keep both sides in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better not to play with Hibernate such OOP games.
Just use this constructor

```
   public Dish(String name, double price, Restaurant restaurant) {
        super(name);
        this.price = price;
        this.dateAdded = LocalDate.now();
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }
```

And save `Dish` after that. Hibernate will not add a new dish to the `Restaurant` object of course. You will have it after reloading the `Restaurant` from the database.

But usually we not work with child objects using `@OneToMany` part of the association. We don't delete a dish from the collection, and save the restaurant to delete a dish from the database.

And usually `dishes` are lazy in the restaurant and is never loaded from database with a restaurant.

`@OneToMany` collection can be useful, when we create a new restaurant with a list of dishes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Dish extends AbstractNamedEntity {
    private double price;
    private LocalDate dateAdded;

    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    public void setRestaurant (Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    public Dish(String name, double price, Restaurant restaurant) {
        super(name);
        this.price = price;
        this.dateAdded = LocalDate.now();
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }
}
```